# Test Case is finished before Thread execution is completed C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, .net-core, nunit

Environment:
Dotnetcore : 3.1,
Nunit : 3.12.0

---

I was trying to write a unit test for a public method in a class which will create a heavyweight orphan thread, when I was trying to run all the unit test cases in my application orphan thread was not executing properly and it was terminating in the middle, due to that other unit test cases are not executing. Below is the error which it was throwing.

`A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern. The active test run was aborted. Reason: Test host process crashed`

```
Code Snippet
// Unit test case logic
[Test(Description = "TestCase. - orphan Thread)]
public async Task OrphanThreadUntiTestCase()
{
     var actual = _repository.SampleMethod();
     Assert.AreEqual(true, actual.Result);

}


// Repository Logic
public class Repository{
constructor(){
}
public SampleMethod(){
 _ = Task.Run(() =>
  {
       HeavyTask();
  });

return true;
}

private HeavyTask(){
// execution of this task was taking more time.
// due to this Task my whole unit test cases are not executed.
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What `SampleMethod` does is to "fire-and-forget" a task.  You should change the method to be async:

```
public async Task SampleMethod()
{
  return Task.Run(() =>
    {
       HeavyTask();
    });
}
```

Then await this method in `OrphanThreadUntiTestCase`:

```
await SampleMethod();
```